# Should my 50mA fuses be blowing up?

Tags: fuses

I am running a PCB that requires me to use a 50mA fuse (F0402G0R05FNTR,) but my PCB consumes a peak current of about 60mA during operation for 24ms every 327ms at 125 Celcius application as shown below.

According to the datasheet the fuse should never blow up at all as the pre-arc time for 60mA is much greater than at least 100 seconds.

I have test it about 4 days at 125C continuous in an oven and the circuit is fine and the fuse did not blow up. Last week at ambient while doing tests on the board the fuse did blow up. Do you think the possible causes might be ESD related?

[image]

Comment: Where does this requirement for a 50mA fuse come from? What is it protecting exactly?

Comment: I take you mean the fuse blows, rather than blows up or are they actually exploding?

Comment: Have you ensured that the DC power source has well-behaved turn-on and turn-off transient response? Could the PCB circuits have latched-up while you were probing during ambient tests? What other input signals go to those PCB circuits, and how are *they* powered up? I ask because power-up sequencing can cause latch-up. Another possible cause of over-current can be floating input pins of logic.

Answer (score 2):

ESD doesn't trip fuses directly.

Fuses blow when there is a prolonged fault condition (~seconds), e.g. [ESD-induced latch-up](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up). For anything faster, don't *rely* on fuses to trip for safety, but also don't rely on them to not trip for function.

Yours is an edge case, where you expected proper function although being on edge of the specs. So even after your 125C test, I wouldn't trust that all deployed units would operate well.

[Your schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDzJc.png) doesn't cover your I/O protection. If ESD happens there, it can cause latch-up in an IC and then draw excessive supply current even at regular power supply voltage.

Comment: Yes thats correct thats why the 60mA power is not enough to trip the 50mA fuse. But the trip time is highly dependent on the current. for 10x or 15x the current the trip time is instantaneous. Which is why i wonder if the ESD of about 300mA or more could have tripped the fuse.

Comment: @FieryFire ESD current can be amps, but the energy is too small to trip a fuse..Latch-up conditions due to ESD, however, typically last indefinitely, so indirectly you could trip a fuse with ESD. For more insight about this, I recommend you post a separate question, including schematics, if interested.

Comment: could you explain whats a latch-up condition ESD? Ive added a bidirectional TVS diode of about 6.5V just before the Fuse. Do you think this would eliminate the ESD and protect the Fuse for normal operation? [schematic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDzJc.png)

Comment: @FieryFire I have added more context in the answer. Please be advised that gradually incrementing the question scope through comments on existing answers is not very welcome on SE. Instead, post new questions on the additional issues.